# Change kunena url from /kunena to /forum

Tags: url, sef, kunena

Simple question that I cannot seem to find an answer to anywhere. When I browse my forum, the sef url is /kunena, I want it to be /forum. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the Joomla backend, go to:

**Menus** >> **Kunena Menu**

Then open the parent menu item (at the top of the list).

In here you can change the **alias** value.